# The most rational answer

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**Question:**

### What if split is absent designedly and letters occupy more spaces obscuring obfuscated prototype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each word of the question

> has one more letter than the corresponding digit of $\pi$ (rounded).
>  `4 2 5 2 6 10 3 7 6 4 6 9 10 9`
>  `3 1 4 1 5  9 2 6 5 3 5 8  9 8`

The phrase 'letters occupy more spaces' in the question suggests extra letters and 'obscuring obfuscated prototype' makes me think of something now being hidden.

The title:

> $\pi$ is a ratio ($circumference \div diameter$)

Comment: The question title is misleading, pi is not rational, it's irrational.

Comment: @Anachor Nearly pi then? :)

Comment: mystery meat pi?